# Flutter container round 3 edge only

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to achieve a bubble for chat like the above picture. My plan: Round 3 edge only of a container.

So far, I have all 4 edge rounded.

```
                 Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'I want to book hotel',
                    style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 10.0, 15.0, 10.0),
                  width: 200.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 20.0 : 10.0,
                      right: 10.0),
                )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using - `BorderRadius.circular(8.0)` you need to use - `BorderRadius.only()`

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(22.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(22.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(22.0)))
```

Output:

[image]